# connection refused while using firebirdsql to connect localhost fdb file

Tags: python, firebird

I'm trying to read fdb files in Ubuntu using firebirdsql:

```
conn = firebirdsql.connect(host='localhost', database='db.fdb',
                           user='sysdba', password='masterkey', charset='utf8')
```

But while connecting, it just said Connection refused.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebirdsql/__init__.py", line 94, in connect
    conn = Connection(**kwargs)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebirdsql/fbcore.py", line 595, in __init__
    self.sock = SocketStream(self.hostname, self.port, self.timeout, cloexec)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebirdsql/socketstream.py", line 46, in __init__
    self._sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

the code works well on Windows Server, but on Ubuntu it can't establish the connection, how can I solve it?

Comment: 1) Is Firebird server of proper version (to support FDB file format) installed and running on the machine? 2) also `database='db.fdb'` would mean next to nothing without specifying the folder (full path). Where this file is located on Linux computer? On the Windows machine the Firebird server probably is installed and running.

Comment: On [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/firebirdsql/) it is said that firebirdsql  is written in pure Python : no C compiler needed or fbclient library, so I haven't install firebird server on the Linux machine, while on the Windows machine there's actually a Firebird server running. I replaced the actual path of the fdb file for convenience, it's located in my home folder.

Comment: You have a gap in logic here. Pypi page says "firebirdsql package is a set of Firebird RDBMS (https://firebirdsql.org/) bindings for Python".  BINDING - what is it? it is a connector, a glue, a proxy, an intemediate, a link in a chain. Your Pypi package promises to be a link, connecting your Python program to "Firebird RDBMS". If there is no "Firebird RDBMS" in your environment - then there is nothing to connect to! It would be the same as copying that Pypi package to the computer and installing Firebird but removing Python altogether. A chain link needs BOTH left and right neighbors

Comment: Do a simple thing, try to make your Linux program connect to your Windows Firebird server and database. Assuming those computers are connected to one another and no firewalls would be in the way. See the difference.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood that firebirdsql could directly read the fdb files without a server, so I got so wired that it got connection refused error while the fdb file was actually located on the localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you indicate you don't have a Firebird server installed on your machine. As there is no server listening on localhost port 3050, you get the *connection refused* error.

That firebirdsql, the driver you're using, is pure Python doesn't mean it can open database files by itself, it means it doesn't use a native library to establish a connection, but that it implements the Firebird TCP/IP wire protocol in Python. You will need a Firebird server (either localhost or remotely) to connect to.

Also: a server normally won't be able to access files in your home directory.

Comment: In my application I need to read data from both mdb and fdb files, so now I'm trying to use unixODBC(by using pyodbc) and mdb,fdb odbc drivers to read them in a unified way. I installed unixODBC, build [mdbtools](https://github.com/mdbtools/mdbtools) from source code, and download firebird odbc driver. Here are my configurations:

Comment: `[MDBTools]
Description = MDBTools Driver
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libmdbodbc.so
SetUp = /usr/local/lib/libmdbodbc.so

[Firebird]
Description = Firebird Driver
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libOdbcFb.so
Setup = /usr/local/lib/libOdbcFb.so`but while trying to connect to mdb files, unixODBC driver manager said that Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libmdbodbc.so' : file not found, but the file does exist there. Is it still necessary to install server when using odbc?

Comment: I'm trying to install firebird server, but after installing I can't start the server. `sudo systemctl start firebird` returns `Failed to start firebird.service: Unit firebird.service not found.`

Comment: I think these are too hard for a beginner of database...

Comment: The error in your second comment has nothing to do with Firebird, but with that MDBTools Driver. In any case, yes, even when using ODBC, you will need a Firebird server to connect. As to the error in your third comment, this could indicate that you don't have Firebird installed on your system, or that it isn't setup to be launched through systemctl. I can't help you with that. Consider asking on the [firebird-support Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support).

Comment: @清晨的雾 i am sure that Firebird 2.x is absolutely easy on Windows, almost as easy as SQLite and much easier than mySQL. FB 3 is harder, and FB on Linux is probably too. Mostly because there is way more Linux distros than Windows distros (and there is only one init system in Windows not dozen as in Linux), and way less people caring to keep packeting every Firebird version for every Linux distro than there are for MySQL/Maria. I guess the better course to you know would be to go to your Linux distro support forum and ask about help in packeting Firebird for it. P.S. systemd freaks me out too :-)